# Android Log File IO - File/Directory not found error

Tags: android, file-io

I am trying to create a file for logging, but when I create the file I am getting a File or Directory not found error. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. This is the code that makes the file:

```
    File directory = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS,"test");
    directory.mkdirs();

    File file = new File(directory, fileName.trim()+".txt");

    if(!file.exists()){
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }

    }
```

The error is being thrown by createNewFile(). What is causing this error?

Comment: Did you added write permission in manifest and Documents Directory exist ?

Comment: Yes, I have read and write permissions added to the manifest.

Comment: And directory documents exist?

Comment: I'm not sure, I thought it existed by default. Is that not the case? I'm not getting any errors or warnings from Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS.

Comment: Check result of directory.mkdirs();

Comment: It returned false, so directory documents doesn't exist. How to I create it? Or is there a better way to write to Documents/test/log.txt?

Comment: Check below answer

Comment: You should use `getExternalPublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)` to retrieve the normal Documents directory.

Comment: `directory.mkdirs();`. Dont call mkdirs blindly. But only if the directory not exists. And then check the return value as it might fail to create one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was caused by the app not requesting permissions at runtime as greenapps suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Document directory first.

```
File docDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS); 
    if (!docDir.exists()) {
       if(docDir.mkdirs()) {
       File directory = new File(docDir,"test");

    } else {
     // Unable to create document directory. check Run time permissions
    }
}
```

Comment: `Create a Document directory first.`. Wrong. Make use of the standard documents directory. You also forget to look at the return value of mkdirs.

Comment: mkdirs() is still returning false

Comment: @greenapps Updated my answer and added check for Directory creation

Answer (score 0):

You should use `getExternalPublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)` to retrieve the normal Documents directory.

```
directory.mkdirs();
```

Dont call mkdirs blindly. But only if the directory not exists. And then check the return value as it might fail to create one.

Comment: I have been testing this a little. getExternalPublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) gives me access to the Documents directory like you suggested, but when I try to use it to create a sub directory mkdir still returns false. I tried both mkdir and mkdirs.

Comment: Which Android version in use? Did you request write permission in manifest file? Did you add code to request the user to confirm these permissions at runtime for android 6 and above?

Comment: I am creating the directory like this:  File directory = new File(getExternalPublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS), "test"); Both directory.mkdir() and directory.mkdirs() return false. Why can't I create the directory?

Comment: I didn't request the permissions at runtime. That is what I am missing. I will do that and test again.

Comment: The user can also go to android-settings-apps-your app and switch the permission on manually.

Comment: That was my problem. After add the code to request permissions at runtime, everything worked as expected. Thanks for the help!